# Running source ~/.bashrc doesn't load the right version of node when using nvm

Tags: bash, bashrc, node.js

I have placed this at the bottom of my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# NVM
. ~/nvm/nvm.sh
nvm ls
nvm use 0.8
nvm ls
```

This is the output when I load a terminal:

```
Last login: Mon Apr 29 16:28:17 on ttys010
    v0.4.7     v0.6.14      v0.8.4      v0.8.6     v0.8.12
current:  v0.8.12
default -> 0.8 (-> v0.8.12)
Now using node v0.8.12
    v0.4.7     v0.6.14      v0.8.4      v0.8.6     v0.8.12
current:  v0.8.12
default -> 0.8 (-> v0.8.12)
usr$ which node
/Users/Vaughan/nvm/v0.8.12/bin/node
```

And when I run `source ~/.bashrc`:

```
usr$ source ~/.bashrc
    v0.4.7     v0.6.14      v0.8.4      v0.8.6     v0.8.12
current:  v0.6.1
default -> 0.8 (-> v0.8.12)
Now using node v0.8.12
    v0.4.7     v0.6.14      v0.8.4      v0.8.6     v0.8.12
current:  v0.6.1
default -> 0.8 (-> v0.8.12)
usr$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

As you can see, the version of `node` is incorrect. It no longer references the `nvm` version.

What on earth could be going wrong?

Comment: Check the order in which the `$PATH` is evaluated

Comment: In OS X, `.bashrc` isn't loaded from anywhere, really. Put your code in `~/.bash_profile` instead.

Comment: I load `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile` like so: `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi`

Comment: Okay, maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly, but wouldn't the answer be: don't run `.bashrc` again? It works when you load the terminal, right? Maybe `nvm.sh` doesn't like to be called twice.

Comment: I want it to run in each terminal. And there are times when I adjust env vars from `~/.bashrc`. `nvm.sh` appears to not set the path when already activated. I think this is an issue to raise with `nvm` considering it is recommended to run it from `~/.bashrc`. Thanks for your help though, got me thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! (Please don't forget to reply to users with @slhck – I didn't get any notification.)

Answer (score 1):

I removed these two lines from the top of `~/.bashrc` and moved them to `~/.bash_profile`.

```
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/Vaughan/bin:$PATH"
```

Now I can run `source ~/.bashrc` without disrupting Node or nvm.

The issue was that nvm does not reset the PATH when run.